# Matplotlib - tight layout placement and adjusting padding

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphics

I am running a function that runs multiple sub-functions, each calling for an axis in a plot (for example, a 2x2 matplotlib subplot). While the figure is working out, I'd like to reduce some of the padding, notably for the x axis. Is there anything I can do to minimize some space and offer more room in the plots for the data to be seen?

Currently, I am calling `plt.tight_layout(pad=0.1, w_pad=0.05, h_pad=0.05)` at the end prior to calling `plt.show()` and plotting; should I opt to use for whenever an axis is established instead? I am also using the labelpad modifier when generated each axis title; however, this is done as part of each sub-function that works on its own axis and `tight_layout()` is called at the end, so perhaps it is pointless?

Finally, here is what I am able to get with the above padding settings, and I cannot seem to improve it. Any suggestions for alternative ideas?
[image]

Comment: Hey there, did you take a look at `subplots_adjust` and `gridspec`? https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-gridspec-py. In my experience, I only called `tight_layout` at the end, never saw any benefit to calling it multiple times.

Comment: If you are wondering why there is a large space between the second column ylabel and the first column axes, that is because you have a large "1000" overhanging the first column to the right, and tight_layout is not allowing the 2nd-column ylabel to overhang that tick.